# Having trouble with time.sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffering

When I run, for example:

```
print("[",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("=",end=" ")
time.sleep(1)
print("]",end=" ")
```

Nothing happens for 10 seconds, then the whole [ = = = = = = = = = = ] appears. How can I prevent that so that it can act as a sort of progress bar?

Comment: oww, that is nasty. What about loops? They never did anything bad to deserve such blatant ignorance! Have a heart, man!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with sys.stdout.write() with time.sleep() in a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808832/problems-with-sys-stdout-write-with-time-sleep-in-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a progress bar belongs to `sys.stderr`, which is (very conveniently and not coincidentally at all) not buffered. So I suggest you:

```
print("=", end=" ", file=sys.stderr)
```

instead.

PS a synopsis of the standard input, output and error streams in POSIX-conformant operating systems can be found in Wikipedia: [Standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).
In a few words: stdin is the input to a process; stdout is the useful output of a process, the results; stderr is for warnings, errors and out-of-band (e.g. progress bars) output.

Comment: What would that do? I don't understand, I'm just a beginner. Would that still output it to the shell?

Comment: @Waterfox: yes, it would still output to the “terminal”. Go ahead and try it.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the difference?

Comment: @Waterfox: first, using `sys.stderr` you can `print` without having to call `sys.stdout.flush` every time. Second, a progress bar is a *diagnostic* about the… progress (what else?) of a program, it's not and should not be part of the *standard output* of the program; progress bars and printing to the *standard error* are a match made in heaven. If that still confuses you, ignore everything I said after “Second,” in this comment.

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand what you mean, now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

Try flushing stdout after each print:

```
import sys

print("=",end=" ")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

[sys.stdout.flush()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush)

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush `stdout` using `sys.stdout.flush()` every time you want to write the updates.